# pass array from JavaScript to viewbag and use it in controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

my school project is about building an app for employees of airplane company. we decided to combine identity for log in, and our tables with data required by the project. we modified the registration form to use email and password from identity, and additional data from our employees table. this works and updates both tables at the same time. we then added roles (pilot, mechanic, flight attendant) and upon selecting role, javascript loads additional options for these roles (for attendant you get to select a language they speak, and for mechanic which planes they are licensed to repair. for pilots we just enter date of last medical exam). Pilots work fine, but since attendants can speak more languages, and mechanics can be licensed for more than one type of plane, we wrote js to multiply these particular select fields by clicking on + icon. then we didn't know how to get this multiple pieces of data back into controller so it can update the database. teacher told us to gather all the values selected inside of javascript array (done) and pass it to viewbag on the view. we never did such example in the class, and googling this comes out with tons of ways to pass the viewbag into javascript but not the other way around. teacher told us just to declare the viewbag on top of controller as null, then fill it up on view, and use it where needed in controller to loop over and input data into into database. I just need to know how to pass js array into viewbag in the view, and I assume the code I wrote inside of controller would do the rest

my js code is called when register button is clicked (it returns proper int array into console)

```
function Langs() {
    var trig= document.querySelector(".trig")
    let langs= [];
    trig.onclick = () => {
        let languages= document.querySelectorAll(".languages"); 

        for (let language of languages) {
            langs.push(Number(language.value)); 
        }
        langs= [...new Set(langs)]; 
        console.log(langs);
        return langs;
    }
}
```

inside of my controller, I have loop like this:

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.JeziciZaUnos)
   {
        Attendant att= new Attendant(){
            att.attId= model.Employee.empId,
            att.langId = Convert.ToInt32(item)
        }
        db.Attendant.Add(att);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Every attempt to pass JS array into this viewbag, either directly from controller or within a view, fails, and C# sees just a string such as "Langs();" rather than js function.

How do I get this JS array into the viewbag, or is there another way to collect multiple values from repeated select boxes, and loop trough them on controller side?

Answer (score 2):

I would rather suggest you pass data to your controller via AJAX calls on the event you desire. [Here is the example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/post-the-data-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-using-jquery-ajax)
Using ViewBag for this seems quite a futile endeavour for me.